# Will not using a new motorcycle damage it?

Tags: motorcycle, long-term-storage

I bought a new motorcycle in may. I rode it home (30 km / 18 mi) and stopped it.

I was planning to break in the engine in a couple of days but, unfortunately, due to some unforeseen health circumstances, I was unable to drive it.

I'm recovering and I hope I'll be able to drive in a week or two. The bike was left with less than 2 liters of gasoline inside.

I was wondering if I may have damaged it and if I need to take care of something before starting it again.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think the only way you could somehow damage the bike was doing some inappropriate_to_new_bike things while riding those 30 km. You might protect it from weather conditions (direct sunlight, rain, etc.) but it applies to any vehicle. There are some tips like filling the gas to prevent rust in tank, covering mufflers, removing the battery but they are for winter storage imho.

Comment: Fuel spoiling in the gas tank and fuel system is always a problem with long term storage of any gasoline powered vehicle, Fuel should be drained completely and run the engine until it stalls to remove most of the fuel from the rest of the fuel system. How long has it been since you rode it??

Answer (score 2):

its been only two months, thats not a long time to let a car or bike sit idle. The gasoline is still good. Maybe the battery needs some recharging but i do not expect anything else.

Like Ghukas noted there are items like filling up the tank or removing the battery, but tho months are not long enough to start worrying about those things.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to comment.  I agree however with MadMarky - you shouldn't have much trouble after only 2 months.  You *probably* don't need to drain the fuel, but it sure wouldn't hurt it any to top off the tank to freshen it a bit.